# Simple jq Destructuring Alternative Operator ?// example

Tags: jq

This question is about a simple example using Destructuring Alternative Operator: `?//` of `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Advancedfeatures).

Consider

```
filter:
.[] as [$a] ?// [$b] | {$a,$b}

input:
[[3]]

output:
{
  "a": 3,
  "b": null
}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/Rik3oc8vgA

But I was expecting output:

```
{
  "a": 3,
  "b": null
}
{
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
```

If I try:

```
filter:
.[] as [$a] ?// [$b] | {$a,$b}, if $a != null then error("err: \($a)") else {$a,$b} end

input:
[[3]]

output:
{
  "a": 3,
  "b": null
}
{
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
{
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/f-jBqB9EdZ

As you can see, this time

```
{
  "a": 3,
  "b": null
}
{
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
...
```

is outputted.

Can you explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The [Destructuring Alternative Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#DestructuringAlternativeOperator%3A%3F%2F%2F) `?//` can be used to fall back on interpreting the context according to an alternative **structure** if the first one fails. This can be useful if you cannot be sure if you have to process, say, an array or an object. Checking with something like `type` (again and again if the structure is deep) may be tedious. `?//` provides an easier way using the usual destructuring which has already been introduced with the [Variable Binding Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Variable%2FSymbolicBindingOperator%3A...as%24identifier%7C...) `as` but with providing alternatives to fall back on.

For instance, if you want to capture a value that is either the first item of an array or the value of a field literally called "first" in an object, then you can use `… as [$a] ?// {first: $a}` to capture that value into `$a` regardless which structure (out of the two) was present ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2PCEt6CrIH)). Of course, for more complex structures you can use more variable bindings, which would be set to `null` if they weren't used in the eventually matching structure.

That said, having `… as [$a] ?// [$b]` is quite pointless as it captures the same structure anyway, and only fall back on `$b` if there is an error with `$a` (we'll come back to that later). Having instead for example `… as [$a] ?// $b` would make a lot more sense as it could fall back on setting `$b` to the original input if it could not be evaluated as an array making the destructuring with `[$a]` fail ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KMmfjcGFzC)).

Therefore, `.[] as [$a] ?// [$b] | {$a,$b}` from your example, when fed with `[[3]]`, will expectedly produce `{"a": 3, "b": null}` and nothing else.

---

Regarding your second example combining `,`, `if` and `error`:

If `error` is used on its own, execution seemingly fails as expected:

```
.[] as [$a] ?// [$b] | error("failed")
```

```json
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): failed
exit status 5
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/x5xmRuarpK)

But actually, `?//` holds two possible contexts that could be passed on to the next filter. After the first one fails because of the following `error`, the next one is evaluated. After that one fails in the same way, the (second) failure is propagated to the output (while the first one is implicitly caught). However, `debug` can expose that there were indeed two evaluations:

```
.[] as [$a] ?// [$b] | debug | error("failed")
```

```json
["DEBUG:",[[3]]]
["DEBUG:",[[3]]]
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): failed
exit status 5
```

Therefore, in an `if` statement using `$a != null` as a condition which evaluates to `true` in the first alternative, but to `false` in the second, while having an `error` in the `then` branch, will by implication eventually reach the `else` branch without actually failing, as the one `error` could be caught and a second was never raised.

```
.[] as [$a] ?// [$b] | if $a != null then error("failed") else "surprise" end
```

```json
"surprise"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/r6-tnXub4R)

And showing the variables reveals that infact the second alternative was valid for the `else` branch:

```
.[] as [$a] ?// [$b] | if $a != null then error("failed") else {$a,$b} end
```

```json
{
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RlyRxLnvo7)

Combining the above with using a [Comma](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Comma%3A%2C) turns the output into a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

```
.[] as [$a] ?// [$b]
| {inif: false, $a, $b},
  if $a != null then error("failed") else {inif: true, $a, $b} end
```

```json
{
  "inif": false,
  "a": 3,
  "b": null
}
{
  "inif": false,
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
{
  "inif": true,
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BFCY5JH8iY)

While evaluating the first destructuring alternative, the first object (with `inif: false`) is being produced. Then, an error occurs in the `then` branch, and the second destructuring alternative is being evaluated. This produces once again the first object (with `inif: false`) and, as by condition it can now follow the `else` branch of the `if` statement, the other object (with `inif: true`) is being produced as well.

Comment: thx a lot! actually i think it is XOR: 1^1=0, 0^0=0, 1^0=1, 0^1=1

Comment: i still don't understand why two {inif, ...} is produced.

Comment: @Logan Passing on the outputs of a filter as input into other filters will compute as many times as there are outputs (because each filter processes only one input at once), and as many times as there are other filters (because each of them is promised the same input). The overall result is the cartesian product. This is the way how jq handles this in general. Try out [this](http://jqplay.org/s/18PHoUSkLV) simple example by adding more items to one or both of the arrays and watch how the number of outputs changes. Also, looking at input/output not as value(s) but as state or context may help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with:

```
[[3]] | .[] as [$a] ?// [$b] | {$a,$b}
```

which is evidently equivalent to

```
[3] as [$a] ?// [$b] | {$a,$b}
```

The first part of this says, in effect:

- first set $a and $b to null;
- next, try to match [3] with [$a], and if that fails, then try to match [3] with [$b]

Since [3] can be matched with [$a] by setting $a to 3, $b retains its original value, i.e. `null`.

The non-obvious thing here is that `error` triggers backtracking: on backtracking, the assignment of 3 to $a is undone, and $b is assigned the value 3 instead.

QED

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, and because it has been rather neglected so far:

While the other answers explain in depth why your examples behave the way they do, why the errors occur etc., this should focus on how to achieve your "expected output" instead.

As a matter of fact, you can also utilize the behaviour of the [comma](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Comma%3A%2C) here. Set one context to `{a}`, another one to `{b}`, and evaluate `{a,b}` for both.

```sh
.[] | {a:.[]}, {b:.[]} | {a,b}
```

```json
{
  "a": 3,
  "b": null
}
{
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/D8U4aVnTDE)

Answer (score -1):

The following follows up on pmf's example:https://jqplay.org/s/BFCY5JH8iY

It aims to shed light on how `,` works like cartesian product.

There are two inputs passed to the last filter.

| input | left of comma | right of comma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $a is 3 and $b is null | {inif: false, a: 3, b: null} | error |
| $b is 3 and $a is null | {inif : false, a: null, b: 3} | {inif: true, a: null, b: 3} |

Final output is in this order: `{inif: false, a: 3, b: null} error {inif: false, a: null, b: 3} {inif: true, a: null, b: 3}`(error is suppressed).

So the output is:

```
{
  "inif": false,
  "a": 3,
  "b": null
}
{
  "inif": false,
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
{
  "inif": true,
  "a": null,
  "b": 3
}
```

Have a look at this too: https://jqplay.org/s/tC98BzFAzM

This time its:

| input | +10 | +20 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 21 |
| 2 | 12 | 22 |

And output is:

```
11
21
12
22
```

Am I under right track pmf?

Comment: You are definitely on the right track figuring out how jq's comma can produce a cartesian product. (In fact, your abstract example `.[] | .+10, .+20` is way better than mine as it models closer the original setup.) But be wary to thoroughly relate your answer to your question, as others might not instantly grasp how your focus has shifted from sheding light on jq's destructuring alternative operator to understanding jq's comma and the cartesian product, which probably is reflected in the downvotes (it wasn't me). That said, I hope you're confident at using `?//` now.